# How to search nested array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have this nested array:

```
array = [
      ["A", "X"],
      ["B", "Y"],
      ["C", "Z"]
]
```

Is there a function that returns "B" when I provide "Y" and "C" when I provide "Z"?

Comment: Picky-picky point: it would better to change 'and "C"' to 'and return "C"'. Initially I thought you were providing "Y" and "C" and wanted "B", which seemed odd and made the sentence undecipherable. Of course, I may be the only person in the room who read it that way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[rassoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-rassoc) might be what you need.

`array.rassoc("Y")` would return `["B", "Y"]` and you can use `first` to get only the `"B"`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find` method.

```
array = [
  ["A", "X"],
  ["B", "Y"],
  ["C", "Z"]
]


str = "Y"
arr = array.find{|a| a[1] == str}
puts arr[0] if arr
# => B
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, you can convert it to a Hash, if you need to do many lookups and the array is biggish:

```
hash = array.map(&:reverse).to_h
hash["Y"]
# => "B"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such internal function out of the box, but one might easily create one:

```
▶ λ = ->(input) { array.detect { |e| e.last == input }.first rescue nil }
#⇒ #<Proc:0x0000000437f150@(pry):10 (lambda)>
▶ λ.('X')
#⇒ "A"
▶ λ.('Y')
#⇒ "B"
▶ λ.('QQQ')
#⇒ nil
```